# Mongodb response slows down incredibly after 200,000 records

Tags: node.js, performance, mongodb

Currently our task is to fetch 1 million records from an external server, process it and save it in the db. We are using `node.js` for fetching the records and `mongodb` as the database.

We decided to split the process into 2 tasks, fetching the records and processing it. Now we are able to fetch all the records and dump it in mongo but when we are trying to process it(by processing I mean change a few attribute values, do some simple calculation and update the attributes), we see drastically slow response in mongodb updates around `200,000` records.

For processing the data, we take batches of 1000 records process it, update the records( individually) and then go for the next batch. How could the performance be made better?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on your db? If so, drop them while doing the import.

Comment: @dbcb we have done that. Currently there isn't any index on the collection.

Comment: Why not use the bulk API for updates? - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/

Comment: @BatScream : That API will improve performance only when updates are idempotent. otherwise it is similar to single update.

Comment: How are you grabbing batches of records? Are you using skip and limit? or a query to get the records.  Skip/Limit will slow down after a while as you get farther and farther from the start point.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to maintain response speed in mongoDB after long data then use mongo sharding and replication in your database and collection

***replication:-***
A replica set in MongoDB is a group of mongod processes that maintain the same data set. Replica sets provide redundancy and high availability, and are the basis for all production deployments. This section introduces replication in MongoDB as well as the components and architecture of replica sets. The section also provides tutorials for common tasks related to replica sets.

[Replication Link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/)

***sharding:-***
Sharding is the process of storing data records across multiple machines and is MongoDB’s approach to meeting the demands of data growth. As the size of the data increases, a single machine may not be sufficient to store the data nor provide an acceptable read and write throughput. Sharding solves the problem with horizontal scaling. With sharding, you add more machines to support data growth and the demands of read and write operations.

[Sharding Link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/)